# Is it possible to use Ionic as front-end and node.js's npm library as back-end?

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm

I want to build a cross platform mobile app for an Arduino based home automation system. Is it possible to use Ionic as front-end and node.js's npm library as back-end? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's a very popular combo to write your services in nodejs and use ionic for UI. In one of the project I used [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com), Ionic, Node and [Elastic](https://elastic.co). The whole combination is enough to fulfill most of the business needs.

Comment: Thank you Sir !! :)